# Download Image by clicking on button using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

I have this image with a data URL and a button.

Now, I want to download that image using JavaScript. So far I got this code but after download the image its saying: It looks like we don't support this format.

```html
<img src="data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoA....." class="filterImage">

<input type="button" name="button" value="Save" id="saveImg" class="btn btn-primary float-right">
```

```js
function saveImage() {  
  let image = document.querySelector(".filterImage");
  var img = new Image(); 
  
  img.onload = function() {
        let canvas = document.createElement("canvas");
        let width = canvas.width;
        let height = canvas.height;
        let context = canvas.getContext("2d");
        context.drawImage( image, 0, 0, width, height );    
  }

  img.src = image.src;
   
  let link = document.createElement('a');
  link.download = "image.png";
  link.style.opacity = "0";
  link.href = image.src;
  document.body.append(link);   
  link.click();
  link.remove();
}
        
saveImage(); // For testing purpose I am directly calling this function
```

Is there anything I am wrong? How can I solve it?

Comment: Consider using an `a` element instead?

Comment: you mean this link: `let link = document.createElement('a');`

Comment: Well that is a link, but I meant not using a button in the first place...

Comment: Well, any working code will be helpfull for me

Comment: @creativeartbd which browser are you using?

Comment: It's Chrome browser.

Comment: Surprising. This code is working on my system for a jpg image converted to data URI.
I suspect an issue with the image.

Comment: You need to append the canvas to the DOM. Also: I would declare the canvas and the context outside the `saveImage()` function

Answer (score 0):

Some browsers do not allow links to be clicked programmatically (by way of ~`link.click()`); for example, when I try to do so, Chrome navigates to "#blocked".